# DLL Searching and Loading on Windows7

Tags: windows, dll, exe, portable-executable

Nowdays I've met a strange problem about DLL searching and loading on Windows7:

I'm sure that I set the correct Path Environment Variable such as : ......;C:/SomeProblem/Bin

and under the C:/SomeProblem/Bin folder, there are some important DLLs which will be used in my program, then I use depends.exe to check my program's dependencies, everything seems OK...

But when I try to run my program, the lack-of-dll error occurs(0x13 error, not so sure...),if I want to fix this problem, I have to:

1. copy all the important dll to my program folder or
2. copy all the important all to system32(system folder not so sure...) folder

Neither of them is great solution ...

Dose anyone knowns something about this ? Please give me some guides, Thanks very much !

Comment: Don't turn OS folders into garbage cans. Keep your exe's and dll's together in "Program Files".

Comment: Actually I just want to separate those DLLs into several folders, but I can't figure out the method......(setting Path EV seems not so correct...),do you know something about this ?

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details on how DLLs are searched. Also, if you modify PATH in one console window, it won't affect other console windows and other programs and if you modify PATH in system properties, the change will only be seen in newly started programs/console windows and won't affect the ones that are already running.